# Vuex state does not update without a page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm building a single page application where users can see different pages depending if they've logged in or not. The login call works perfectly and an authorization token is saved in the Local Storage.

**The setup**: I've set up a getter called `loggedIn` which returns `true` if a token is set on the state. This is the exact code in my `auth.js` module of the store:

```
const state = {
  accessToken: TokenService.getToken(),
}

const getters = {
  loggedIn: (state) => {
    return state.accessToken ? true : false
},
```

The TokenService has this:

```
getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)
}
```

**The problem**: when the user logs in, the token is correctly saved in the Local Storage (I can see it). However, the Vuex panel in DevTools shows the getter `loggedIn` as `false` and the `accessToken` as `undefined`. **The problem fixes itself when I manually refresh the page.** The store is then properly populated.

What am I doing wrong? I need the store to be reactive so I can show some pages or others depending on the `loggedIn` getter.

Comment: If you have another problem, please ask a new question. Changing or expanding the question after receiving answers invalidates the existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local storage isn't a reactive data so when it changes, there is no way for vuex store to get notified.

what happens is that when your app loads `getToken()` is called at the very beginning and since user isn't logged in yet it returns `undefined`, when user logs in, local storage is updated but `getToken()` doesn't get called again.

BUT! now you have the data in your local storage so when you refresh your page manually `getToken()` is called and return a `Truthy` value.

what you can do is to write an `action` to update `accessToken` and call it when user is logged in.

something like this:

```
api.getToken(URL, userData).then((result) => {
   // if user is logged in successfully call the action
   if (result) this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateAccessToken');
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me advance in the problem, although I now have a second issue. So the state is properly updated now without refreshing the page (which is what I asked for, so thanks a lot), BUT back in a component where I read this getter from a computed property `isLoggedIn`, it's not updating reactively... I will do some research, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @HelenaSánchez glad it helped. and about your second problem, what is your 'accessToken' state when its updated? also it would help me if you upvote my answer or check it as correct answer IF it actually helped ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer but my account is new so it said it wouldn't appear as public, sorry. About my accessToken state, it has the token as a string when logged in.

Comment: @ thanks a lot :) when you check the getter from vue dev  tool does it have the correct value?

Comment: hey, I just solved this by making `isLoggedIn` a mapState property instead of a computed... All is working as expected now :)

Comment: @HelenaSánchez great, keep up the good work;)

Comment: @HelenaSánchez how did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem previously. Sometimes it's just a case of the Vue devtools not refreshing. The state is likely updated as expected.
In your `loggedIn` function, try console logging, ie

```
loggedIn: (state) => {
    console.log("token:", state.accessToken)
    return state.accessToken ? true : false
}
```

Vue devtools doesn't do this often. You can right click in the devtool window and refresh frame. It updates your state and corrects itself. An annoying but though

**EDIT**
At the time of successful auth, as well as setting the token in local storage, I would definitely also call a mutation to, at that same point in time, set the accessToken property on the state. You already have it, just set it rather than reading it from localStorage each time. Fetching it from local storage should just be a check you do on first load to see if the user is authed or not..if they are, or once they are, save it to state and access it that way through your app

Comment: Unfortunately I get a `token: undefined` in the console after logging in. Refreshing the devtool window does nothing either... Refreshing the whole page gets me the right token though

Comment: Responding to your edit:
I already have a mutation called `loginSuccess` that goes:

```
loginSuccess(state,{ accessToken }) {
    state.accessToken = accessToken
 }
```

This receives the accesToken from the api call.